# How can I update a config file using a list of domains as input?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have two files: domainList and config.cnf.  The domainList file simply has a list of domains like so:

```
facebook.com
yahoo.com
youtube.com
```

The config.cnf is a config file and has the same list with a little different format.  I need to write a script that will update the config file when the list has been updated.  I can execute a bash script whenever the first list is updated.  Here is the format of the list in the config file...

```
*other config options/entries*
[my_list]
WWW.1 = facebook.com
WWW.2 = yahoo.com
WWW.3 = youtube.com
EOF
```

So, if yahoo is removed and ebay is added in domainList and I run my cool bash script I need the config file to be updated like so...

```
*other config options/entries*
[my_list]
WWW.1 = facebook.com
WWW.2 = youtube.com
WWW.3 = ebay.com
EOF
```

To complicate things (slightly) the domains can have subdomains and wild cards (ie. news.google.com or *.google.com).  Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be appreciated!  How do I do it without getting the numbers all out of whack?  It'll probably just need to clear the list and regenerate it every time, huh?

Thanks!

EV

Comment: Maybe it is overkill, but I cannot help but remember the Python's [ConfigParser module](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple script to achieve that:

```
# delete all lines after [my_list]
sed -i '/my_list/q' config.cnf

# add the domain list to the bottom of the config
awk '{print "WWW." NR " = " $0}' domainList >> config.cnf
```

This script could be written as a one-liner with awk or sed, but the above is (hopefully) quite clear in its approach.

Comment: Awesome!  I really like this answer.  Very clear.  The only problem I have with it is the first line deletes the [my_list] line too.  I need that line to remain.  In my script I just echo'd the line back in in between your two lines.  If there is an easy way to modify the sed line to not delete the matching line then let me know.  Otherwise I will just go with the echo. ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: Is that definitely with the latest version of the answer (i.e `/my_list/q`)? My [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11040843/revisions) had `/my_list/,$d` which *did* clobber the [my_list] line, but `q` should quit *after* printing that line (unless another version of sed treats this differently).

Comment: yeah, it prints that line to the console...not to the file.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess `q` doesn't always play nice with `-i` (BSD sed chooses to not change the original file). The first revision is probably more robust across different versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FIN=domainList
FOUT=config.cnf

echo "config.cnf template header" > $FOUT
awk '{ print "WWW." FNR " = " $1 }' $FIN >> $FOUT
echo "config.cnf template footer" >> $FOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner in awk

```
awk '
BEGIN{var=1}
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} 
var && /WWW/{var=0; for (x=1;x<=length(a);x++) {print "WWW." x " = " a[x]};next}
!var && /WWW/ {next}
1' domainList config.cnf > config.cnf_new
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat domainList 
facebook.com
youtube.com
ebay.com

$ cat config.cnf
*other config options/entries*
[my_list]
WWW.1 = facebook.com
WWW.2 = yahoo.com
WWW.3 = youtube.com
EOF

$ awk ' 
BEGIN{var=1}
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} 
var && /WWW/{var=0; for (x=1;x<=length(a);x++) {print "WWW." x " = " a[x]};next}
!var && /WWW/ {next}
1' domainList config.cnf
*other config options/entries*
[my_list]
WWW.1 = facebook.com
WWW.2 = youtube.com
WWW.3 = ebay.com
EOF
$
```

Answer (score 0):

bash with a touch of awk

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ $line = '[my_list]' ]]; then
    awk '{print "WWW." NR " = " $0}' domainList
    echo "EOF" # is this literally in your config file?
    break
  fi
done < config.cnf > tmpfile && mv tmpfile config.cnf
```